# How to convert Android Gradient Drawable (XML) to Flutter Gradient?

Tags: android, android-layout, flutter, android-xml, android-drawable

I have this gradient as a Splash Screen for android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient
        android:angle="315"
        android:startColor="@color/colorSplashStart"
        android:centerColor="@color/colorSplashStart"
        android:endColor="@color/colorSplashEnd"
        android:centerX="50%"
        android:centerY="15%"
        android:type="linear"/>

</shape>
```

I use this gradient drawable as `android:windowBackground` os a "SplashTheme" so this will load immediately and be shown during the app's start up instead of a blank white screen.

Now I must transition from this gradient to a Flutter Gradient and this is how I do it:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
      end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 1.0),
      colors: [
        colorGradientStart,
        colorGradientEnd
      ],
    ),
  ),
  child: Column(),
);
```

May problem is that the two gradients do not exactly match each other and so it is noticable that the gradient is shifting color. I would prefer to have both gradient's to be equal. Can anyone guide me how to convert Android Gradient Drawable to Flutter Gradient? Or is there any other way to match both gradients?

Comment: Did you try SweepGradient?

Comment: @Artem, haven't tried that yet. Can you guide me here?

Comment: just look inside gradient.dart

Comment: @Artem, Actually I already did right after you commented!! Looks like exactly what I'm looking for!! :D Thanks!!

Comment: Add solution to your post and close it.

Comment: I will i just dont have the time now :)

Comment: @Artem apparently that is not what I need. :(